# How to check whether an XML node set is empty in R?

Tags: r, xml, rvest, xml2

I'm writing a function that iterates over XML nodes in R; for this I've been looking for a verb that affirms or denies the presence of an empty XML-nodeset (something like `isEmptyNodeSet`).

In other words, a function that returns `TRUE` if a case like the following occurs:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(xml2)
"https://www.admin.ch/ch/d/gg/pc/ind2010.html" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("a.adminCHlink, div#spalteContentPlus h2 ~ ul") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_nodes("strong")
#> {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Thanks so much in advance (and sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm an XML-rookie)!

Comment: You could check the `length` of the return node set.  If length==0 then no nodes were returned.

Comment: `is_empty <- function(x) if(length(x) == 0) TRUE else FALSE`

Comment: Ha, `is_empty` is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very very much @Chase! Also thanks to @Dave2e, this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `is_empty <- function(x) if(length(x) == 0) TRUE else FALSE` (thanks @Chase).

Or use `rlang::is_empty()` or `purrr::is_empty()` respectively, which does exactly the same.

The code then becomes:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(xml2)
"https://www.admin.ch/ch/d/gg/pc/ind2010.html" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("a.adminCHlink, div#spalteContentPlus h2 ~ ul") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_nodes("strong") %>%
    rlang::is_empty()
#> [1] TRUE
```